# Why is the melting point of PCl3 less than that of PCl5?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, intermolecular-forces, melting-point

From just the IB chemistry bonding chapter information, you would normally deduce that $\ce{PCl3}$ and $\ce{PCl5}$ are both covalent molecules.

However, as $\ce{PCl3}$ has a dipole moment, it has dipole-dipole intermolecular attractions, implying that  $\ce{PCl3}$ has a higher melting point than $\ce{PCl5}$, which only has London dispersion forces.

So why is it that $\ce{PCl5}$ has a higher melting point than $\ce{PCl3}$ (I saw online that  $\ce{PCl5}$ is an ionic solid)?

Comment: We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field due to issues it gives rise to; see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: Maybe it is related to energy needed to break the bonds in case of both PCl3 and PCl5. See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40702/is-the-p-cl-bond-energy-same-in-pcl5-and-pcl3

Comment: What is "IB"? [International Baccalaureate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Baccalaureate)?

Comment: Yes @PeterMortensen.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because $\ce{PCl5}$ does something which is not immediately obvious from its molecular formula: it autoionizes and becomes an *ionic* solid $\ce{PCl4+PCl6-}$. As such, it has much stronger interactions than $\ce{PCl3}$ with its mere dipole-dipole attractions, hence the higher melting point.

If not for that fact, you deduction should have worked just fine.

Comment: Is there any mathematical way or just method to deduce that $\ce {PCl5}$ is an ionic solid? Or is that from observation.

Comment: No, I don't think this can be deduced via logic alone. As for more _mathematical way_, in chemistry this usually implies that you are going to end up in a nocturnal abyss of quantum chemistry, which is not what you want, believe me.